# Command not executing inside shell script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(</var/www/sym_monitor/man.txt)


if [ "$value" == "true" ]; then

     ps -ef|grep sym |grep -v grep |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;


(cd /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin;sudo ./sym --port 8082 --server);

fi
```

The second command inside brackets is not executing any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is the name of the script?

Comment: restart.sh is the name of the script.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? How do you execute the script?

Comment: No error message! I execute using root inside cron every 10 mins

Comment: Try executing it directly (without cron).

Comment: It is working fine when I run directly but I need to run it for every 10 mins using cron.

Comment: In which user's crontab do you have the script?

Comment: Inside root crontab

Comment: Then why do you use sudo?

Comment: The script requires sudo.

Comment: Why? Without additional parameters, sudo is used to execute a command as the root user. Inside a script executed from root's crontab, sudo can't have that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You must use an absolute path with `sudo`, for security reasons:

```
( sudo /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server );
```

Check the output of `sudo -l` to confirm. From the `sudoers` man page (1.7.x):

> A `Cmnd_List` is a list of one or more commandnames, directories, and
>        other aliases.  A `commandname` is a fully qualified `filename` which may
>        include shell-style wildcards (see the Wildcards section below).

`sudo xargs` works because `xargs` is (almost certainly) found in a trusted path (`/usr/bin`).

Also, check out `pgrep` and `pkill`, it will save you the needless `ps` pipe acrobatics.

You have the potential for resource leaks and other unwanted behaviour with an unconditional `kill -9`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/why-not-kill-9-a-process .

**Update** you've added that you run this via root's crontab -- root has no need to use `sudo`, and in some cases root may be *prevented* from running `sudo`, check what `sudo -l` says when you are root. If you want to to be able to start a program (that doesn't switch its own uid) as a specific userid then the common way is `su - username -c "command"` .

Comment: Im trying these things. I will let you know after my cron got executed.

Comment: No it is not preventing the root from running sudo bcoz the first command also got sudo in it and it is working absolutely fine. Any more suggestions?